# jQuery Validator's "required" not working when value is set at statup

Tags: jquery, validation, input, text, jquery-validate

I have a problem with jQuery Validator. I want to use "required" property on a text input. It doesn't work when input has set value attribute by HTML code (tested on Firefox (3.5), and on IE 8 - on IE it works a bit better).

Story:
1. Page loads;
2. value is cleared;
3. focus is changed.
4. Nothing happens but the error message should be displayed;
5. getting back to the field and typing some characters.
6. changing focus;
7. getting back to the field;
8. clearing the field.
9. Error is displayed even before leaving the field.

The HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <script src="Web/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Web/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" value="test" /><br />
        <input type="text" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var validator = $("form").validate({

                rules: {
                    name1: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                     name1: "bad name"
                },
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the `onfocusout` handler to make this work like you want (more eager):

```
$(function() {
    var validator = $("form").validate({
        rules: { name1: { required: true, minlength: 2 } },
        messages: { name1: "bad name" },
        onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); }
    });
});
```

You can see the [old broken demo (like your question) here](http://jsfiddle.net/qYXFV/) and the [updated one with `onfocusout` that works here](http://jsfiddle.net/qYXFV/1/).

Answer (score 1):

for unobtrusive validation when your validator has been defined already need to modify Michel answer:

```
var validator = $('form').validate();

validator.settings.onfocusout = function(element) {
    $(element).valid();
};
/*validator.settings.onkeyup = function (element) {
    $(element).valid();
};*/
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to say which validation the message was for:
try this:

```
 messages: { 
             name1:
                   {
                      required : "This is a required field",
                     minlength: "Please enter 2 chars or more"
                   }
            }
```

Michel

Comment: It's not necessary. If you provide only one message it used always. Even so, it's not the case, because in "step 9" the validations starts to work correctly.